# Add TableViewer Data in preference Store + eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have a preference page with a table viewer inside it and each row of the table is an object containing a string ,background color and foreground color.

Is it possible to store the data of this table viewer in the preference store, as the preferences are key/value pairs how can i store this info when I click apply and also also populate the table later from preference store?

```
@Override
protected void performApply() {
    for (TableItem item : this.viewer.getTable().getItems()) {
        Content c = (Content) item.getData();
        String name = c.getName();
        RGB bc = c.getBackgroundColor();
        RGB fc = c.getForegroundColor();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a standard way to do this. You could use one entry with comma separated values or multiple entries with key names 'xxx1', 'xxx2', ....

For `RGB` values the `StringConverter` class will convert to/from a String suitable for the preferences:

```
RGB rgb = ...

String rgbString = StringConverter.asString(rgb);

RGB rgb = StringConverter.asRGB(rgbString);
```

(also handles a number of other types).

Since you have three values to save for each row it would be simpler to use three preferences per row which might be something like:

```
int row = 0;
for (TableItem item : this.viewer.getTable().getItems()) {
    Content c = (Content) item.getData();
    String name = c.getName();
    RGB bc = c.getBackgroundColor();
    RGB fc = c.getForegroundColor();

    String nameKey = "name" + row;
    String bcKey = "bc" + row;
    String fcKey = "fc" + row;

    prefStore.setValue(nameKey, name);
    prefStore.setValue(bcKey, StringConverter.asString(bc));
    prefStore.setValue(fcKey, StringConverter.asString(fc));

    ++row;
}

prefStore.setValue("rowCount", row);
```

Read:

```
int rows = prefStore.getInt("rowCount");

for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++row) {
    String nameKey = "name" + row;
    String bcKey = "bc" + row;
    String fcKey = "fc" + row;

    String name = prefStore.getString(nameKey);
    RGB bc = StringConverter.asRGB(prefStore.getString(bcKey));
    RGB fc = StringConverter.asRGB(prefStore.getString(fcKey));

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks . How can I load these preferences from the .pref file ?

Comment: You will probably have to set another preference with the number of rows. Then you loop doing getValue for the same keys.

Comment: How about one preference in .pref file per table viewer row , with row as key and value is comma separated name, bc and fc ?

Comment: StringConverter.asString uses comma separators which makes that difficult.

Comment: Can you give me some rough idea about the code I need for getting the values form pref file

Comment: There is no getValue(String) method for prefStore

Comment: Should be getInt